# How to write bash or shell script in SSM run command and execute in linux ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ssm

I want to run the bash or shell script in Linux using the SSM run command. But I don't want to write it on the Linux server and execute it remotely using the SSM command. I want to write a script in the run command itself.

Is there any way to run a script from the AWS console? Apart from the run command is there any other way to run the whole script?

I am referring to the multiline script not only one command.

Answer (score 0):

First option using aws "CloudShell" service (available only in specific region).

Alternately, you can execute shell script using AWS Systems Manager > Run Command > Run a command, Select the type of command that you want to run & Search by keyword
" AWS-RunShellScript " (Linux platform only).

In Command Parameters, specify a shell script or a command to run.

PS : For both Windows & Linux platform, search by keyword " AWS-RunPowerShellScript "

Answer (score -1):

You can write a bash or shell script in SSM run command and execute it in a linux ec2 instance using the following command:

aws ssm run-command --document-name "MyShellScript" --instance-ids "i-1234567890" --parameters "MyScriptParameter=Value"

This will execute the "MyShellScript" script on the instance with ID "i-1234567890" and pass in the parameter "MyScriptParameter" with value "Value".